# Altering arrays to add/remove entries at each time-step in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops, matrix

This question, probably has a simple solution but I cannot think of how to do it...

So I have a script as follows:

```
# ------------------ MODEL SETUP ----------------------------------------# simulation length
t_max <- 50

# arena
arena_x <- 100
arena_y <- 100

# plant parameters

a <- 0.1
b <- 0.1
g <- 1

# list of plant locations and initial sizes
nplants <-dim(plantLocsX)[1]*dim(plantLocsX)[2]

iterations<-5
totalBiomass<-matrix(0,nrow=iterations,ncol=1)

# starting loop 

sep <- 10


# Original matrix
plantLocsX <- matrix(rep(seq(0,arena_x,sep), arena_y/sep),
                    nrow=1+arena_x/sep,
                     ncol=1+arena_y/sep)


plantLocsY <- t(plantLocsX)

plantSizes <- matrix(1,nrow=nplants,ncol=1)

# Plot the plants
radius <- sqrt( plantSizes/ pi )
symbols(plantLocsX, plantLocsY, radius, xlim = c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), inches=0.05, fg = "green", 
        xlab = "x domain (m)", ylab = "y domain (m)", main = "Random Plant Locations", col.main = 51)


# Calculate distances between EACH POSSIBLE PAIR of plants
distances <- matrix(0,nrow=nplants,ncol=nplants)

for (i in 1:nplants){
  for (j in 1:nplants){
    distances[i,j] <- sqrt( (plantLocsX[i]-plantLocsX[j])^2 + (plantLocsY[i]-plantLocsY[j])^2 )
    }
}


# ------------------ MODEL RUNNING ---------------------------------------
```

I need to alter the arrays containing plant locations and plant sizes so that at each time step, entries are removed and added (simulating mortality/reproduction, respectively). The "distances" must be updated with plant locations and sizes after each iteration...I can only think of complex ways to do this: destructing and constructing new matrices at each time step to fit the new number of elements but there must be functions to make this simpler....any advice?
Many thanks!!